# near login does not recognize my account in guest-book example

Tags: nearprotocol

I am following the instructions to use guest-book example in this [link](https://examples.near.org/guest-book)

but after I create a new account and try to login to near from terminal using `near login` I could not find the created account in the browser when it opens automatically. Then I tried to login from the terminal by passing my account but I got the following error :

```
Which account did you authorize for use with NEAR CLI?
Enter it here (if not redirected automatically):
guest.testnet
The account you provided [ guest.testnet ] has not authorized the expected key [ 
ed25519:4FRg1h... ]  Please try again.
```

After reviewing the steps again, I realized that the link for a wallet account is creating an account in wallet.nearprotocol not in the wallet.testnet link. when I Create the account using [wallet.testnet.org](https://wallet.testnet.near.org/) it works fine. now my question is what is the difference between creating an account in testnet versus nearprotocol as both of the accounts end by testnet network extention.

can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is the question?
Regarding `near cli` it is using `testnet` rpc by default,
you can see that when you call `near -help`:

```
--nodeUrl, --node_url      NEAR node URL  [string] [default: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org"]
      --networkId, --network_id  NEAR network ID, allows using different keys based on network  [string] [default: "testnet"]
```

So it means if you will not pass one of those arguments, it will by default open [testnet wallet login link](https://wallet.near.org/)
And it will open it in the default. So you can log in if you previously imported the account in that browser, or you can import it right away using one of the import options.

Now regarding wallets, main net accounts are ending on `.near` not on `.testnet`.

The difference is that mainnet wallet is using mainnet rpc endpoint.
Here are the properties of mainnet and testnet in Guest Book [config.js](https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book/blob/master/src/config.js):

```
{
    networkId: "mainnet",
    nodeUrl: "https://rpc.mainnet.near.org",
    walletUrl: "https://wallet.near.org",
    helperUrl: "https://helper.mainnet.near.org",
    explorerUrl: "https://explorer.mainnet.near.org",
},
{
    networkId: "testnet",
    nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
    contractName: CONTRACT_NAME,
    walletUrl: "https://wallet.testnet.near.org",
    helperUrl: "https://helper.testnet.near.org",
    explorerUrl: "https://explorer.testnet.near.org",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But there is still something I do not get:
 if you create an account from the [link ](https://examples.near.org/guest-book#:~:text=Visit%20NEAR%20Wallet%20and%20make%20a%20new%20account) provided by the instructions of the example which I followed you will see that the URL of the wallet none of the above here is the [wallet URL](https://wallet.nearprotocol.com/). 
Which mains as I understand if I want to use that account I should put the wallet configuration in config.js?

Comment: @Rasha You can use `testnet` from config.js, because https://wallet.nearprotocol.com/ is also using testnet rpc. 
You can see it when you open the link and on the top of the page it will print: 
Test-only Wallet(rpc.testnet.near.org)